# Dropdown menus display in theory but not in practice

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have several drop-down menus I am trying to get to work correctly, and I am having inconsistent results. Below is the code that works when I use the "try it" function on w3www schools, but when I put it into my sheets the buttons show up with correct style format but clicking them doesn't show me the menus? It doesn't seem to matter if I put the entire block into my html doc or if I break it up into the separate html/css/js docs I'm building on. Any suggestions? I've now spent about 2 hours trying different things with mixed results but nothing to suggest I've found the source of the problem. It's worth noting, this is one of 6 drop-down menus I'm trying to implement. Thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #930d0d;
    color: black;
    padding: 8px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #930d0d;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 4px 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #000000}

.show {display:block;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Clickable Dropdown</h2>
<p>Click on the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>


<div class="dropdown">
<button id="myBtn" class="dropbtn">How many miles are you willing to drive?        
</button>
  <div id="mDistance" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#5">5</a>
    <a href="#10">10</a>
    <a href="#Distance">15</a>
    <a href="#Distance">20</a>
    <a href="#Distance">25</a>
    <a href="#Distance">30</a>
    <a href="#Distance">35</a>
    <a href="#Distance">40</a>
    <a href="#Distance">45</a>
    <a href="#Distance">50</a>
    <a href="#Distance">55</a>
    <a href="#Distance">60</a>
    <a href="#Distance">65</a>
    <a href="#Distance">70</a>
    <a href="#Distance">75</a>
    <a href="#Distance">80</a>
    <a href="#Distance">85</a>
    <a href="#Distance">90</a>
    <a href="#Distance">95</a>
    <a href="#Distance">100</a>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick = function() {myFunction()};
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("mDistance").classList.toggle("show");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

***edit: the rest of the buttons, as requested. i didnt re-copy the css since it's the same for all of them. i grouped each dropdown with it's corresponding script

```
    <div class="dropdown">
<button id="myBtn" class="dropbtn">What kind of friendship are you looking     for?</button>
  <div id="mGoal" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#Goal">PenPals</a>
    <a href="#Goal">Spontaneous</a>
    <a href="#Goal">Planned Events</a>
</div>
<script>
document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick = function() {myFunction()};
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("mGoal").classList.toggle("show");
</script>
    <div class="dropdown">
<button id="myBtn" class="dropbtn">What time of day are you most available?        
</button>
  <div id="mDay" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#day">Morning</a>
    <a href="#day">Night</a>
    <a href="#day">Both</a>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick = function() {myFunction()};
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("mDay").classList.toggle("show");
</script>
    <div class="dropdown">
<button id="myBtn" class="dropbtn">How do you recover energy?</button>
  <div id="mVert" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#vert">Introvert</a>
    <a href="#vert">Extrovert</a>
    <a href="#vert">Ambivert</a>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick = function() {myFunction()};
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("mVert").classList.toggle("show");
</script>
<div class="dropdown">
<button id="myBtn" class="dropbtn">How many years older or younger than you are you comfortable making friends?</button>
  <div id="mAge" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#age">5</a>
    <a href="#age">10</a>
    <a href="#age">15</a>
    <a href="#age">20</a>
    <a href="#age">25</a>
    <a href="#age">30</a>
    <a href="#age">35</a>
    <a href="#age">40</a>
    <a href="#age">45</a>
    <a href="#age">50</a>
    <a href="#age">55</a>
    <a href="#age">60</a>
    <a href="#age">65</a>
    <a href="#age">70</a>
    <a href="#age">75</a>
    <a href="#age">80</a>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick = function() {myFunction()};
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("mAge").classList.toggle("show");
```

EDIT NUMBER 2:
[this is what it looks like if i take out the script connecting the separate js page, and put the button scripts under their html codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXwVE.jpg)
the css page is re-linked. so what i cant figure out is if it still a js problem (there is zero js code of any kind except for the button lines in this example) or if there is something with the css or html itself? un-linking the css page didnt help, i tried that first.

3RD EDIT
realized i hadnt updated all of the function issues, now THAT is fixed and im left with this. which is better.......but now it might just be a z=designation issue? maybe?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHHpm.jpg)

Comment: Hi, the code you provided works. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vgOJJj Maybe there is conflicting javascript on the page you're implementing?

Comment: Did you check your console to see if there is an error being thrown?

Comment: Hey Tails, sorry to ask the obvious question but, are the other dropdown elements by chance using the same Id as this one? Or maybe... think you could provide a full version with all 6 drop downs so we can better look at this?

Comment: edited to include all the buttons, if you need any other part of the coding let me know.......or even if it's more likely to be a css/js/html issue? i can show whats on the pages if need be

Comment: @MichaelCoker im bookmarking that link lol ty. and yeah it WORKS.........just not where i need it to work :/

Comment: @DaveCripps i'm not sure if i would recognize one :(

Comment: @OrlandoParedesHamsho sorry forgot to tag you in the other comment (not sure totally how the commenting/notifications work here yet) i added the other buttons

Comment: @Tails your `myFunction()` functions aren't closed, but they're all referencing the same function name and ID for the click handler, so they aren't going to open unique menus.

Comment: @MichaelCoker THANK YOU! that makes sense! i'll work on that

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicate ID's on the buttons you've assigned a click handler to, and they all reference the same function, `myFunction()`, which keeps getting overwritten because you define it over and over.

You would either need to make these functions and ID's unique, so that the click handler can be assigned to unique lists, or build this in a more modular way with a single function. I re-wrote this a little so your ID's are unique, and updated the click handlers so they are assigned to the unique ID's with unique functions.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .dropbtn {
        background-color: #930d0d;
        color: black;
        padding: 8px;
        font-size: 16px;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
        background-color: #930d0d;
    }
    
    .dropdown {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        min-width: 160px;
        overflow: auto;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a {
        color: black;
        padding: 4px 8px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #000000}
    
    .show {display:block;}
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <h2>Clickable Dropdown</h2>
  <p>Click on the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>


  <div class="dropdown">
    <button id="myBtnGoal" class="dropbtn">What kind of friendship are you looking     for?</button>
    <div id="mGoal" class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#Goal">PenPals</a>
      <a href="#Goal">Spontaneous</a>
      <a href="#Goal">Planned Events</a>
    </div>
    <script>
      document.getElementById("myBtnGoal").onclick = function() {
          document.getElementById("mGoal").classList.toggle("show");
      }
    </script>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button id="myBtnDay" class="dropbtn">What time of day are you most available?        
</button>
      <div id="mDay" class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#day">Morning</a>
        <a href="#day">Night</a>
        <a href="#day">Both</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      document.getElementById("myBtnDay").onclick = function() {
          document.getElementById("mDay").classList.toggle("show");
      }
    </script>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button id="myBtnVert" class="dropbtn">How do you recover energy?</button>
      <div id="mVert" class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#vert">Introvert</a>
        <a href="#vert">Extrovert</a>
        <a href="#vert">Ambivert</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      document.getElementById("myBtnVert").onclick = function() {
          document.getElementById("mVert").classList.toggle("show");
      }
    </script>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button id="myBtnAge" class="dropbtn">How many years older or younger than you are you comfortable making friends?</button>
      <div id="mAge" class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#age">5</a>
        <a href="#age">10</a>
        <a href="#age">15</a>
        <a href="#age">20</a>
        <a href="#age">25</a>
        <a href="#age">30</a>
        <a href="#age">35</a>
        <a href="#age">40</a>
        <a href="#age">45</a>
        <a href="#age">50</a>
        <a href="#age">55</a>
        <a href="#age">60</a>
        <a href="#age">65</a>
        <a href="#age">70</a>
        <a href="#age">75</a>
        <a href="#age">80</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      document.getElementById("myBtnAge").onclick = function() {
          document.getElementById("mAge").classList.toggle("show");
      }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: well now they work separately (thanks guys!) but i think theres still an issue bc they wont show on the page?

Comment: ok so i tried putting the css for the buttons as inline text, and taking out the connecting css link in the html to see if the css was causing the issue. and that didnt do anything to help. so it's probably still an html or js problem.......but not sure what

Comment: alright so when i put the working script back into the separate js file, it stops working again. but when it's inline text on the html it works? just needs to show up on top

Comment: @Tails do you have any errors in your browser console?

Comment: the script has the same issue in both internet explorer and chrome (i dont have anything else installed) and the instructions for checking beyond that idk what to do with bc im using notepad++ and they instructions have nothing to do with that, as far as i can tell :/

Comment: @Tails in chrome, to view the browser console, right click on some text on the page, and click "inspect," then in the little area that pops up (those are the "dev tools"), click the "console" tab and tell me if you have any errors there.

Comment: @Tails I got a notification you want me to review an edit with your screenshot? Not sure why I need to review it, but I looked at the screenshot and I need to see the right side of that line. In fact, it would help if you clicked on whatever's to the right of that line - it should take you to some code with a mark where the error is.

Comment: yeah i tried to edit my post and clicked the wrong thing (im tired) lol

Comment: the comments arnt letting me tag you anymore, i dont know why. the /* is hiding code that isnt finished/working yet. honestly it's mostly ideas that i need to make workable later, at this point

Comment: @Tails weird, the comment looks fine. Is this site live? Can I see that whole file?

Comment: not live yet :/ my plan is soon, but i have to get paid from my job before buying a domain

Comment: i can add the whole file

Comment: actually, can i email it to you? instead of constantly editing this post? my email is ka.la_fire_thinker@yahoo.com